# control c causes printing of garbage

Tags: c, mingw

I am making a small test program, which demonstrates a crude console interface.

The program is a sub-par typical get-line, respond program that doesn't even recognize "exit", and expects you to force exit by pressing control-c. It's done on Mingw32.

What puzzles me is that when control c is pressed. the program displays garbage before exitting.

eg:

```
<client> Welcome to Concept Program.
<client> type h for help menu.
<you> meep
<client> 'meep' is not a recognized command.
<you> *ctrl-c*
<you> <client> 'meep' is not a recognized command.
```

The code for this program is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    puts("<client> Welcome to Concept Program.");
    puts("<client> type h for help menu.");

    while (1) {
        char msg[200];
        printf("<you> ");
        gets(msg);
        if (strcmp(msg, "h") == 0) {
            puts("<client>");
            puts("-help menu-");
            puts("h: shows this menu");
            puts("-----------");
        } else {
            printf("<client>'%s' is not a recognized command.\n", msg);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to know how to stop it from printing garbage in this scenario, and if possible, an explanation why this occurs.

I know it's a silly question, but any help is appreciated!

---

Note/2022: I have revisited this old program as I got a notification, and there are several immediatly evident flaws(some of which are nitpicky and unsubstantial):

1. The program did not `#include <string.h>` despite using strcmp.
2. The program did not `setvbuf(stdout, (char *)0, _IONBF, 0)` nor `fflush`, which makes the output inconsistent on different terminals/tty.
3. On top of all the potential issues with `gets`, it's considered deprecated, and potentially even removed in newer compilers.

The original bug does not manifest on my current machine even with the original code.

Here is the slightly improved code without a complete rewrite:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    setvbuf(stdout, (char *)0, _IONBF, 0);
    puts("<client> Welcome to Concept Program.");
    puts("<client> type h for help menu.");

    for (;;) {
        char msg[200];

        printf("<you> ");
        scanf("%200s", msg);
        
        /* scanf ALWAYS leaves "\n" in stdin after reading. Clear stdin. */
        {
            int ch;
            
            ch = getchar();
            while ((ch != '\n') && (ch != EOF)) {
                ch = getchar();
            }
        }
        
        if (!strcmp(msg, "h")) {
            puts("<client>");
            puts("-help menu-");
            puts("h: shows this menu");
            puts("-----------");
        } else {
            printf("<client>'%s' is not a recognized command.\n", msg);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have the impression that the output you show had not been produced by the code you provide.

Comment: I do not see garbage values in your sample output.

Comment: Don't use `gets()`, it's not C anymore, and was dangerously bad even when it was.

Comment: Also the code misses to prototype `strcmp()`.

Comment: changed code, output to be actual experiment.

Comment: It is dangerous, but I don't know any other way to do it.

Comment: Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: oh, I know that one, but Im using gets in this particular case to make code more to the point, avoiding manually chomping "\n". But normally, I use fgets.

Comment: OK, but if you deliberately want to write bad programs, and you ended up with one, where's the problem?

Comment: I am curious why the garbage gets printed. Even if I replace gets with fgets, the problem persists. Yes its a bad program, but i'm pretty sure the experiment is finely isolated, eg persists in properly written environments.

Comment: Have you considered actually *checking* the return value of that ill-fated `gets()` rather than assuming it *worked* and relying on potentially indeterminate data in the aftermath? (i.e. complying with [Henry Spencer's 6th Commandment](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ten-commandments.html)).

Comment: "Ctrl+C" does not get processes by `gets`; it sends a (lower level) `signal`, which probably ends up messing up your output. Try intercepting this signal as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189650/execute-c-program-till-ctrlc-hit-in-the-terminal

Comment: The issue is that this is on Mingw so trapping signals is a bit tricker than on unix shell, but since the program is intended to be for unix shell, I guess I can just prevent the issue altogether by capturing ctrl-c... It doesn't solve the problem as is sadly. I was hoping for a solution for mingw as well, but it might not be realistic.

Answer (score 1):

Write like this instead, you need to check the return value from fgets, if ctrl-c is pressed it will return NULL.

```
   while (1) {
        char msg[200];
        printf("<you> ");
        if (fgets(msg,sizeof(msg),stdin) != NULL)
        {
          if (strcmp(msg, "h") == 0) 
          {
              puts("<client>");
              puts("-help menu-");
              puts("h: shows this menu");
              puts("-----------");
          } 
          else 
          {
              printf("<client>'%s' is not a recognized command.\n", msg);
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried doing the null check on fgets, and the garbage is still printed, eg "<you> <you>" at the end.

Comment: odd since i tried the code in mingw and it seems to work. are you on linux?

Comment: I am running it on windows.

Comment: I ran it on windows as well. strange.